# Why are some tags in Visual studio code showing red underline?

Tags: image, anchor

[Some tags are showing red underlines and I am not sure why they are showing..??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXtZC.png)

My VS code is showing some tags in red underlines but I cant figure out why. The code runs with no errors.

Can anyone tell why it is happening??

Comment: probably the syntax error